# Jquery callback with synchronous animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, animation, synchronous

In my jQuery plugins I often expect to have some callbacks defined by the user like in the simple example below

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myplugin = function(options) {
        var s = $.extend({}, options),
            $this = $(this);

        if (typeof s['initCallback'] === 'function') {
            s['initCallback']($this);    
        }
        $this.animate({width: '+=300'}, 3000);   /* animation in plugin */
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Sometimes the defined callback contains synchronous code like this, and this code works as I'm expecting

```
$('#mydiv').myplugin({
    initCallback : function(mydiv) {
       $('<div>This is synchronous, so it will entirely executed before animation</div>')
           .insertBefore(mydiv);
    }   
});
```

but in some other case the callback could defines an asynchronous animation like this

```
$('#mydiv').myplugin({
    initCallback : function(mydiv) {
       $('<div>animations are not synchronous here</div>')
           .insertBefore(mydiv)
           .hide()
           .fadeIn(4000); /* animation in callback */
    }   
});
```

in this last case we have  two animations that clearly overlap, because after execution of my `initCallback()` the remaining plugin code is not properly executed on `fadeIn()` callback.

So I'm asking: does it exists a common jQuery pattern to deal with both kind of code (async/sync) to be sure that the `initCallback()` will ever terminate the execution, no matter of which code it defines? Or am I require to code both the case in two different ways?

Code of this example is available on http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/LKttT/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I realized the problem now: in this exampleI have animations on two different elements and in this case I cannot use a queue, since every element belongs its own queue. So to create a single global queue I should use a plugin like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fxqueues: I'd like a lot to have this natively on jQuery 1.5 so I opened a ticket http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7490

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> .animate( properties, options )
>
> propertiesA map of CSS properties that
>   the animation will move toward.
>
> optionsA map of additional options to
>   pass to the method. Supported keys:
>
> - duration: A string or number determining how long the animation
>     will run.
> - easing: A string indicating which easing function to use for the
>     transition.
> - complete: A function to call once the animation is complete.
> - step: A function to be called after each step of the animation.
> - queue: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the
>     effects queue. If false, the animation
>     will begin immediately.
> - specialEasing: A map of one or more of the CSS properties defined by
>     the properties argument and their
>     corresponding easing functions (added
>     1.4).

You should set **queue** to **false**.

Comment: if I set queue:false, code execution is still async. If I set to true then the animations are synchronous but fadeIn and animate run in inverse order.